# Suggest a good method for having a number with high precision in C#

Tags: c#, key, precision

I am programming on a project which I should store the key of the user to the initial configuration of a machine, I want to write it in C#.

I have an initial configuration which consists of two number R and X0, R = 3.9988 and X0 = 0.5. I want to add the user key to these numbers. for example:

Key: hos110 =>

- R = 3.9988104111115049049048
- X0 = 0.5104111115049049048

104111115049049048 are ASCII codes of the key which are concatenated.

How can I store these numbers?

Is there a better method for doing this?

Update: How about MATLAB?

Comment: I want to have arithmetic operation on R and X0.

Comment: decimal data type precision is limited to 17.

Comment: Decimal is not "limited to 17".  Just try: Console.WriteLine("{0}", 1.1234567890123456789012345678m);

Comment: Yes, Thank you, It's limited to 29.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need infinite precision you need something that is called BigInteger. However these classes are usually only used for scientific calculations (and usually unsuited for stroring the data) which doesn't really seem to match your code sample. If you need to do only general calculations use Strings and then convert them to Decimal for the calculations.

However if you are looking for such a BigInterger Class you can find one [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/biginteger.aspx?msg=2373423).

.Net 4.0 will have a BigInteger built-in-class in the class libraries named `System.Numerics.BigInteger`.

Comment: Depends on which implementation you take. For the two mentioned ones you would have to keep track of the decimal place yourself.

Answer (score 5):

You're not really "adding" numbers. You are concatenating strings.

**Store them as strings.** You can't get much more precise than that.

If you need to perform any arithmetic operations, it is easy enough to convert them to a decimal number on the fly.

Comment: Hi, Thank you, I want to have arithmetic operation on it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really follow why you're using a key as part of a number, but leaving that aside... `System.Decimal` (aka `decimal`) seems like the right tool for the job here.

Comment: Hi, Thank you, I want to have arithmetic operation on it. I think by decimal users' keys is limited to 17 numbers for floating point.

Answer (score 1):

Well, depending on the precision you are trying to achieve, you can probably save these as a pair of [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) values.

However, if this is an ASCII code, you may just want to save these as a string directly.  This will avoid the numerical precision issues, especially if you're going to pull off the 104111... prior to using this information.

Comment: Hi, Thank you, I want to have arithmetic operation on it.

Comment: Why do you want to do arithmetic with a user key?

Comment: It's an initial configuration of a machine for generating a stream based on the user's key for encrypting an image.

Comment: I'd just use System.Decimal then.  It gives you quite high-precision math, so you can do your arithmetic operations with less rounding error.

Comment: decimal data type precision is limited to 17.

Comment: @hossein Margani: That is not true.  Decimals are not limited to 17 bits of precision, especially not when near the origin.  For example, by default, decimal.ToString will preserve the first 28 bits of precision, which is enough for the strings you posted.

Comment: you mean my user key is limited to 9 characters? it's not very good.

Comment: If encryption is the goal why not use tried-and-tested .Net API? Rolling your own encryption rarely works out well (and you're likely not to know you failed). Is it steganography perhaps?

Comment: Thanks, I am creating a new method for image encryption.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are storing a "key", so why not use a String then?

Comment: Hi, Thank you, I want to have arithmetic operation on it.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers are inherently imprecise. I'm not sure what this 'initial configuration' is or why it's a float, but you're not going to be able to tack on a 'user key' (whatever that may be) and recover it later. Store the user key separately, in a string or something.

Answer (score 0):

If these 'numbers' have no numeric value, i.e. you will not use them for mathematical computation then there is no need to store them in a numeric datatype. You can store them as strings.